# Getting attendees/participant details using Domino Data Service

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I am trying to integrate my application with Domino 9.0.1 REST service.Is there anyway i can get attendees information/details of a meeting  through Domino Data Service.http://{host}/Conf.nsf/api/data/documents/unid/{uid}

Comment: Isn't the list of attendees part of the JSON data you get back from server?

Comment: Nope it is not returning that.

Comment: Show the code you are using to retrieve the meeting, and show what you are getting back.

Comment: It is just a REST client (Browser):

Comment: So show your test URL and the results that you get back. We'd really like to help you, but you haven't given enough information. Unless you show us the exact request and the exact results - and tell us what you see in the appoinment when you look at it in Notes, then all we can do is make guesses.

Answer (score 0):

In my test the attendees are in three different items in the data portion.

> RequiredAttendees, AltRequiredNames and INetRequiredNames

```
{
    "@href":"\/xxx.nsf\/api\/data\/documents\/unid\/xxxxx",
    "@unid":"xxxxx",
    "@noteid":"xxxxx",
    "@parentid":"xxxxxx",
    "@created":"2015-04-01T00:58:42Z",
    "@modified":"2015-04-01T19:01:09Z",
    "@authors":
    ["CN=xxxx\/O=org","CN=xxxx\/\/O=org","CN=server\/O=org"
    ],
    "@form":"Appointment",
    "CalendarDateTime":
    ["2015-04-08T15:00:00Z","2015-04-15T15:00:00Z","2015-04-22T15:00:00Z","2015-04-29T15:00:00Z","2015-05-06T15:00:00Z","2015-05-13T15:00:00Z"
    ],
    "STARTDATETIME":
    ["2015-04-08T15:00:00Z","2015-04-15T15:00:00Z","2015-04-22T15:00:00Z","2015-04-29T15:00:00Z","2015-05-06T15:00:00Z","2015-05-13T15:00:00Z"
    ],
    "EndDateTime":
    ["2015-04-08T15:30:00Z","2015-04-15T15:30:00Z","2015-04-22T15:30:00Z","2015-04-29T15:30:00Z","2015-05-06T15:30:00Z","2015-05-13T15:30:00Z"
    ],
    "StartTimeZone":"Z=8$DO=1$DL=3 2 1 11 1 1$ZX=69$ZN=Pacific",
    "EndTimeZone":"Z=8$DO=1$DL=3 2 1 11 1 1$ZX=69$ZN=Pacific",
    "RequiredAttendees":
    ["Attendee1\/org@domain","Attendee2\/org@domain","Attendee3\/org@domain","Attendee4\/org@domain"
    ],
    "AltRequiredNames":
    ["Attendee1\/org@domain","Attendee2\/org@domain","Attendee3\/org@domain","Attendee4\/org@domain"
    ],
    "INetRequiredNames":
    ["attendee1@org.com","attendee2@org.com","attendee3@org.com","attendee4@org.com"
    ],
    "ApptUNID":"xxxx",
    "AppointmentType":"3",
    "lotsmore":"removed ......."
}
```

Comment: Newbs, your response appears to be for a resource in a mail file ("@form": "Appointment").  Anil seems to be requesting a document in a resource reservation database (/Conf.nsf/api/data/documents/unid/{uid}).  I don't think a reservation document retains the attendee list.  That appears to be the root of the problem for Anil.

Comment: @Dave - you are probably correct. I do not use the Resource Reservations with Domino Data Services, and I missed that. What he could do is write a custom rest service in an XPage to find the users mail database and the appointment and return the list of attendees... But that is a lot like work.